# Does it make sense to share 10G Lan between 2 RJ-45 ports?

Tags: networking, network-adapter, gigabit-ethernet, connection-sharing

Observing TRX40 Motherboards for upcoming Threadripper 3000 series.
So, see 2 mobos i like mostly.

1. [Gigabyte TRX40-AORUS-XTREME](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/TRX40-AORUS-XTREME-rev-10/sp#sp)
2. [Gigabyte TRX40 DESIGNARE (rev. 1.0)](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/TRX40-DESIGNARE-rev-10/sp#sp)

First one has this in LAN part of its specification:

> Intel® 10GbE LAN chip (10 Gbit/5 Gbit/2.5 Gbit/1 Gbit/100 Mbit), supporting 2 RJ-45 ports

The question is: when does it come in handy to share 10G Ethernet between two ports?

I quess, it is better to have two independent 1G NICs (every with its own MAC-address as in second one mobo).

Thank in advance for qualified and clear answer.

Comment: Maybe there is a misunderstanding here? The Intel 10GbE LAN chip has two RJ-45 ports that support 10 Gb/s *each*. You could connect to two entirely separate LANs at 10 Gb/s. It is [possible to use two ethernet ports together](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation) though, and that chip may even support it too. If you mean to ask about the benefits of Link Aggregation, then please clarify that.

Comment: I am not sure which one chip is used, just copied string above from specification.

Comment: Probably this mobo intends to be used as a server with highly-intensive networking. If you see second one mobo specification you will see explicit statement: 2 x <some LAN model>. So, there are two different NICs here. That's where this question came from.

Comment: Until those motherboards announce the specific LAN chips being used we can only speculate whether they are a single 2-port NIC or two separate NICs. Many other motherboards in the workstation/enthusiast class have a single NIC with 2 ports. Either way both configurations can still be used for entirely separate LANs at 10Gb/s or whatever the maximum speed of the chipset is.

Comment: @Romen: Gigabyte lists the LAN chip as an Intel X550-AT2, which indeed fits the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AORUS motherboard has an [Intel X550-AT2](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/84329/intel-ethernet-controller-x550-at2.html) chip. There's a 1208 page daatsheet on the linked page, but you don't need to read all of them. On page 20 the overview diagram shows that the single chip has two network interfaces internally, with 2 MAC addresses. The only thing that's shared is the connection to your CPU. This is an internal PCI3 connection which has a raw speed of up to 40 GBit/s, so that's plenty for 2x10Gbit Ethernet.

The chief question with this motherboard would be, *what are you going to connect it to?*

Comment: Consumer application: connect it directly to another (maybe two) PC which also has 10G RJ45, both PCs have nice SSDs. And you may get better VNC experience too.